# JavaScript in Web Development

Tags: javascript

I have done my degree in Computer Science, right now I have got some knowledge in Java, JavaScript, Html, Css, MySql and a bit of PHP. I want to be a Front end developer and  I want some advises because I am now lost. Can anyone give me some idea, Thanks in advance and Have a great day ahead 
By knowing JavaScript in depth, can I be a good programmer?

Comment: This is a great question, but not well-suited to Stack Overflow. You might try https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions

Comment: Not the right place to really post this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to become a front-end or full-stack developer, knowing HTML, JavaScript, CSS and SQL is certainly useful.  What started as a front-end scripting language, JavaScript can now be used for Full-Stack development (e.g. Meteor, Electron).

You can refer to this insightful [The State of JavaScript](https://2018.stateofjs.com/) page to take an informed decision as to which JS library / platform you should pick.

Experiment with them, perhaps build a boilerplate app to really get an idea how the mechanics work, then settle for the one you like most.

Additionally, it's quite essential to familiarise yourself with testing frameworks, and probably a good idea to learn about NoSQL databases (e.g. MongoDB), as they're used a lot in modern Web Apps.